# Can I get when a Facebook profile picture was updated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Android app is retreiving the user's friends list and displaying it to them alongside their profile pics. At the moment I'm refreshing all the pictures from the server every time which is a waste of bandwidth. Is there a way to query when the picture was last updated?

Comment: Whoever voted to close as an offtopic - you're wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve their pictures at all. Just specify the image's `src` like http://graph.facebook.com/zerkms/picture, where `zerkms` is user's name or id

**UPD**: if so - then no. The only thing could help you is `updated_time` field of user's profile, which is changed when user has changed **anything** in his profile (and probably at wall, not sure)

There is a [Realtime API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) that can notify about particular user profile changes but it will not help you in your case

Comment: Oops, forgot to say that it's an Android app instead of a web app. The technology is not really part of the question anyway - either Facebook has a way to do this or it doesn't